# Facebook achievements registration is failing - url is not of type game.achievement

Tags: facebook, achievements

I'm trying to register an achievement on Facebook. I'm registering:

```
url: http://mydomain.com/achievement.php?gca=gc2 
display_order: 300
```

But I get error: `(#3502) Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement`

In my url I have got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# game: http://ogp.me/ns/game#"> <title>Achievement</title> <meta property="og:type" content="game.achievement" /> <meta property="og:title" content="a" /> <meta property="og:url" content="http://mydomain.com/achievement.php?gca=gc2" /> <meta property="og:description" content="x" /> <meta property="og:image" content="http://avatars.gg.pl/1" /> <meta property="game:points" content="25" /> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY-APP-ID" /> </head> <body>TODO</body> </html>
```

What is wrong? I think error tells about something else...

Comment: Some tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723879/registering-a-new-achievement-3502-object-at-achievement-url-is-not-of-type/7773304#7773304

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed it gives this error for a couple of different reasons, none of which has anything to do with the URL not being of the type "game.achievement".

The most obvious one is when the URL does not point to the right location. Verify that by pasting it in a browser (http://mydomain.com/achievement.php?gca=gc2 in your example.)

Another reason I found is when the app doesn't have its 'App Domain' set in the app settings. It doesn't require this for all apps, only for some. I found a hint about this (as the error is obviously no help at all) by entering the URL in the [object debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and enter the URL to your achievement.